# Several data series in the same column to multiples columns

Tags: excel, multiple-columns, series, vba

I have an excel file where in the same column there are multiple series and i want each series into one individual column

Source Table:

```
A          | B
-----------|---------
Series 1.1 | Series 3.1
Series 1.2 | Series 3.2
Series 1.3 | Series 3.3
           |         
           |         
Series 2.1 | Series 4.1
Series 2.2 | Series 4.2
Series 2.3 | Series 4.3
```

Result Table:

```
A          | B          | C          |D
-----------|------------|------------|-----------
Series 1.1 | Series 2.1 | Series 3.1 | Series 4.1 
Series 1.2 | Series 2.2 | Series 3.2 | Series 4.2 
Series 1.3 | Series 2.3 | Series 3.3 | Series 4.3
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Please review the following edit, I assume you are looking to make a new column whenever you encounter one or more blank cells in a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below code to split the data in a column to multiple columns, splitting data is based on blank cells on that column. *(for multiple column you can call this module again)*

Below code reads the cells from Sheet1 : Column('A') : Reads 500 rows

```
Public Sub break_data()

Dim row As Integer: row = 500      'Number of rows to read on a column

Dim wks As Object                  'Source Sheet
Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim wkr As Object                  'Result Sheet
Set wkr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

Dim i As Integer: i = 1
Dim j As Integer: j = 1             'Column that you want to split

Dim x As Integer: x = 1
Dim y As Integer: y = 1

Do While (i <= 500)
    If (Len(Trim(wks.Cells(i, j).Value)) > 0) Then
        wkr.Cells(x, y).Value = wks.Cells(i, j).Value
        x = x + 1
    ElseIf (Len(Trim(wks.Cells(i, j).Value)) = 0) And (x <> 1) Then
        x = 1
        y = y + 1
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Source:

[image]

Result: (After running the vba)

[image]